# Page Break in TRichEdit Control

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am trying to find a way to force a page break in Delphi when Using the RichEdit Controls print method. The Rich Edit control ignores the \page command for some silly reason.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, TRichEdit control just ignores this for the displaying box, and as far as I know, there is no way to force it to show the pages.

If the goal you want is to break pages so a printer can split it into multiple papers, as @SertacAkyuz said, in this case the `\page` will be parsed and the pages will be correctly printed in separate papers.

But if your goal is to display the page breaks graphically, then you'll be depending on a third-party component.

Comment: For a third-party component, TRichViewEdit comes to mind but it's not free nor cheap, however it can do page breaks and a whole lot of stuff more...

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Sample RTF: `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22 page1\par\page page2\lang1033\par}`. This will load and print as two pages, you can save and reload it and then again it will print two pages.

Comment: I tested here, and you're right. I'll just clarify this in my answer then.